# Bootstrap 3 - how to vertically align an image to the bottom of the highest column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zigson/dsqttdv3/).

I can't lose responsive functionality as my issue goes a bit deeper.

If there are some questions, please do not hesitate to ask. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 yellow">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et efficitur ipsum. Fusce accumsan congue diam, et bibendum mauris aliquam</p>
                <img class="col-md-12" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfVm23Mm3GiIQJJnnej43NG1JrrvpFVTqx1QaOGHXFneJPr9ow" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 orange">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et efficitur ipsum. Fusce accumsan congue diam, et bibendum mauris aliquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et efficitur ipsum. Fusce accumsan congue diam, et bibendum mauris aliquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et efficitur ipsum. Fusce accumsan congue diam, et bibendum mauris aliquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et efficitur ipsum. Fusce accumsan congue diam, et bibendum mauris aliquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et efficitur ipsum. Fusce accumsan congue diam, et bibendum mauris aliquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et efficitur ipsum. Fusce accumsan congue diam, et bibendum mauris aliquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et efficitur ipsum. Fusce accumsan congue diam, et bibendum mauris aliquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque et efficitur ipsum. Fusce accumsan congue diam, et bibendum mauris aliquam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can this be done by javascript only?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is abit confusing since you have the img included in the html, but if im understanding it correctly you will need to look into using javascript/jquery to calculate the height of each container and then compare them and then depending on which one is bigger insert the img into that. Below is a small bit of jquery to get you started.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = $('.yellow').height();
    var b = $('.orange').height();    

    if(a > b){
       //do something here
    }
    else {
        //do something else here
    }
});
```

Comment: @user3365721thank you for your effort. I need to align image to the bottom of the higher column. I could to this by absolute position it. Before that I could use your solution. Hopefully this will work.